# IPython.display Video giving an unplayable "empty" video when trying to run an animation from previous plots (Using ffmpeg)

Tags: python, animation, ffmpeg, ipython

I am working on a crater simulation project for a class and am running into a problem when it comes to creating a video. The general project is for us to simulate a surface being hit by craters until it becomes saturated. The code works, however, if I print out every graph in the simulation it would be thousands of graphs until sat is reached and then I would have to manually clip them all together. To circumvent this, I would like to take all the graphs and put them into an animation. I however, have no idea where to even start.

for reference, here is main code block:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import matplotlib.animation as ani

#I have removed the definitions and class implementation for sake of simplicity and space

ani.writers.list()
FFMpegWriter = ani.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps = 10)
fig = plt.gcf()
figure = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_alpha(1.0)

with writer.saving(figure, "sine.mp4", 150):
    while sat_counter !=1:#while loop that will introduce new crater each iteration

        new_crater = generate_crater()
        new_crater.age = sat_counter
        random_crater_list.append(new_crater)

        i =0

        while i < len(random_crater_list):#looping through the crater list and comparing new crater to all others


            old_crater = random_crater_list[i]


            overlap = square_overlap(old_crater, new_crater)#checks if old crater should be covered/removed by new crater
          

            if overlap == True:
                    random_crater_list.remove(old_crater)
                    i=i-1

                    
            else:
                pass

            i=i+1

        sat = Saturation(random_crater_list)# checks the saturation of the graph and returns a a number between 0 and 100
        if sat > 90:
            sat_counter = 1#base condition used to break the while loop

        writer.grab_frame()
plot_craters(random_crater_list)
```

Here is what the final graph looks like
[saturated surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ4vT.jpg)

I have tried to use the IPython.display video:

```
Video("sine.mp4", embed = True, width = 320, height = 320)
```

This however loads an empty video that is unplayable.
[empty video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIOmP.jpg)